# Commerce filter with width, height and length with tolerance

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, search, filter, products

Hope you guys can help.

I need to create a search feature on a craft commerce site that will allow the user to search for products in this principle:

Product Type

Width +- value

height +- value

length +- value

Here is an example of the data.

Front Door

100cm +- 10cm (90cm - 110cm) width

300cm +- 100cm (200cm - 310cm) height

10cm +- 4cm (6cm - 14cm) length

This will be using parameters just not sure how to write the query for this